# My ViewControllers have some frame problmes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app codes. I have used `tabbarviewcontroller` to set `windows.rootviewcontroller` like this:

---

```
navigaitonController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarViewController];

[navigaitonController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"15a4fa"]];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigaitonController];
```

---

i have five `viewcontrollers` like this:

---

```
PhotoViewController *photoViewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
PhotoAlbumViewController *photoAlbumViewController = [[PhotoAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoAlbumViewController" bundle:nil];
videoViewController = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];
MusicViewController *musicViewController = [[MusicViewController alloc] init];
documentViewController = [[DocumentViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *albumNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoAlbumViewController];
UINavigationController *photoNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoViewController];
UINavigationController *musicNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:musicViewController];
[albumNavigation.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"15a4fa"]];
[photoNavigation.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"15a4fa"]];
[tabBarViewController setViewControllers:@[photoNavigation, albumNavigation, musicNavigation, videoViewController, documentViewController]];

tabBarViewController = [[YDRootViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[viewControllers addObject:photoNavigation];
[viewControllers addObject:albumNavigation];
[viewControllers addObject:musicNavigation];
[viewControllers addObject:videoViewController];
[viewControllers addObject:documentViewController];
[tabBarViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

---

In `VideoViewController` I have a `tableview` like this:

---

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.view.frame;
tableViewFrame.origin.y = 64;
tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height - 49;
videoTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame];
[videoTableView setDelegate:self];
[videoTableView setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:videoTableView];
```

---

then i run this, but in my phone, it's frame was right, but after i play a video use `MPMoviplayViewController`, the `tableView's` frame was wrong like `CGRectMake(0, 128, 320, 391)`

how can I solve this problem. please tell me . thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you set the size of tableView? viewDidLoad()?

Comment: yes,- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.view.frame;
    tableViewFrame.origin.y = 64;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height - 49;
    videoTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame];
    [videoTableView setDelegate:self];
    [videoTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:videoTableView];
    
    [self loadData];
}

Answer (score 0):

No need for UINavigationController in UITabBarController, simply set code like this:

```
[self.window setRootViewController: tabbarviewcontroller];
```

Comment: set transulant no for you navigationcontroller